# Suppress Page Header with specific Report Footer with Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I would like to suppress the page header with specific report footer. As an example below

I've tried with `OnLastRecord`, it worked well when it came to page 2. However, when it had more than 2 pages, it didn't work as I wish.

```
|Page Header
|Details
|Report Footer
|Page Footer A
|Page Footer B
|Page Footer C
|Page Footer D
|Page Footer E
```

Currently:

```
Page 1           Page 2           Page 3
|Page Header     |Page Header     |Page Header
|Details         |Report Footer   |Report Footer
|Report Footer   |Page Footer B   |Page Footer D
|Page Footer A   |Page Footer C   |Page Footer E
```

It must be like:

```
Page 1           Page 2           Page 3
|Page Header     |                |
|Details         |Report Footer   |Report Footer
|Report Footer   |Page Footer B   |Page Footer D
|Page Footer A   |Page Footer C   |Page Footer E
```

Answer (score 0):

write a condition on `page header`.

```
if pagenumber=1
then true
else false
```

Comment: How about my data which doesn't have header when it spreads out to page 3 or 4?

Comment: If there is data in pageheader on 3rd and 4th page then that data is also supressed

Comment: Rest of the data in other sections is displayed without any issue

Comment: For assumption, If I have data for 10 pages, I would like to have header from page 1 to page 8 with details and only report footer section A, and there is no header in page 9, 10 because it has footer report section B, C, D, E. So could your `if clause` address my problem?